# Best mobile simulator to view rails developed website

Tags: android, iphone, ruby-on-rails, mobile, simulator

I am using Rails 3.2.8, I want to design website where client want to view website on mobile, if request from mobile automatically it should show mobile view, I am able to achieve this one.

My problem is need to TEST using SIMULATOR which gives feels of various mobile app like iphone, Android, Blackberry & others.

Can any one suggest me please regarding this.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1):

Try this link. It's free mobile website readiness test.
http://www.gomez.com/mobile-readiness-test/

You can also try **Perfecto Mobile Handset Cloud**. It offers you access to real devices via cloud, but it's not free.